# How to retrieve the expiry date of a domain name?

Tags: powershell, whois

I have a long list of domains that I'd like to retrieve the expiry date from periodically using powershell. I know I can successfully whois the domain using the following:

```
$web = New-WebServiceProxy ‘http://www.webservicex.net/whois.asmx?WSDL’
$web.GetWhoIs(‘stackoverflow.com’)
```

However since I just want the expiry date is there a better approach other than using the above method and then retrieving the expiry date from within the returned data? Using the above seems like it would be quite cumbersome on a large scale and I'm hoping for a better way.

Comment: Hmm, whois is not designed to be used by robots, and getting expiry date will anyway generate a request to whois database, so I think the answer is no, there is no better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way would be to use the API of your DNS registrar (if they actually provide an API that is). If they don't provide an API, screen-scraping their web-interface might be your second best option. Both approaches depend on the actual interface, though.